# File names with special characters

Tags: channel-entries, file-uploads, file-manager, files

If a channel entry uses a file that has been uploaded that contains special characters (I've noticed this so far with brackets and commas), it now produces a PHP error saying the file does not exist. The error shows that the file is being searched for with a percent encoded name, so the original file can't be found.

For example, if an image was uploaded called 'image (large).jpg', the PHP error says 'File /var/www/.../image %28large%29.jpg does not exist'.

I think this error was introduced with EE v2.10.0, as these images were used previously with no error. Upgrading to v2.10.1 doesn't change anything.

Has anyone else encountered this error? The only way around it I've found is to download, rename, and reupload any files with special characters in, which is hardly practical.

Comment: Not sure if this is related but I've noticed some recent weirdness in handling filenames with accented characters.  Specifically images that work in Chrome but give 404 in Safari.  Are you using Safari to upload your files?  Do you get the same issue when you use Chrome?

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but I get the same issue in Chrome.

Comment: I'm currently encountering this error - upgraded from 2.9.2 to 2.10.1. Any luck with fixing this?

Comment: Commenting out line 119 of expressionengine/libraries/Mime_type.php:
show_error(sprintf(lang('file_not_found'), $path));

hides the error, and broken images just show up as white file icons like before.

Comment: @Mark Yeah that works - a great fix for the moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, and a solution from EllisLab can be found at https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20972